# Хранение SQL-запросов

Tags: c#, sql

Как лучше хранить текстовые запросы? Чтобы с ними было удобно работать, править, искать. Интересует хранение именно текстовых, без использования ORM. Буду рад услышать любые предложения и примеры из личного опыта

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если это SQL, то возможно вам стоит использовать хранимые процедуры.

Comment: Пожалуй процедуры здесь выиграют у представлений, т.к. есть возможность передачи параметров.

Answer (score 3):

Если эти запросы должны выполняться, то почему бы не создавать представления?
Оно и хранится, и править их можно.

Comment: Хм... А если с базой работают несколько приложений, количество этих представлений может оказаться очень большим, а, та же, SSMS представляет очень ограниченные функции фильтрации. Хотя остается вариант "метить" свои каким-нибудь префиксом

Comment: >Хотя остается вариант "метить" свои каким-нибудь префиксом

Для этого можно использовать схемы, тогда префиксы никакие не нужны.

Answer (score 3):

Храните константами в DAO. Если на каждый объект-сущность к вас будет своё DAO, то поиск запросов не составит труда, а правка приведёт к перекомпиляции всего одного класса. Ни в коем случае не храните их в конфигах. Если до конфига доберутся кривые ручки пользователя, сдохнет вся программа.

Answer (score 1):

В одном из проектов, над которым я работал, запросы хранились в отдельном xml файле в таком виде

```
<queries> 
    <data name="GetName"> 
        <![CDATA[EXECUTE DB.dbo.p_GetName @id, @Parameter1, @Parameter2, @IP]]>
     </data>
     <data name="GetMessagesList"> 
        <![CDATA[SELECT id, Message FROM DB.dbo.f_GetMessagesList(@Id)]]>
     </data>
    ...
</queries>
```

Довольно легко искать запросы. Приложение имело клиент-серверную архитектуру список всех запросов хранился на стороне сервера, и к базе и самому списку имел доступ только "специально обученный" человек. Все программисты получали лишь интерфейс запроса (Названия, например GetName, вх. и вых. параметры). По названию из файла по имени запроса дергался запрос, с помощью ADO.Net создавалась [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx), заполнялся параметрами и исполнялась.
Сами тексты запросов можно хранить либо в этом же файле, либо в виде хранимок, а в данном файле лишь вызов.